# How to combine a javascript value with a php value to a single javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, return-value

I have a number in php, i.e. `25`.

Then, I have a javascript variable which is a number; i.e. `57`.

The php number is extracted from a text file like this:

```
<!-- NOTE: for this example, the value in file.txt is the number 25 -->
<?php 
$the_number = file_get_contents("file.txt");
?>
```

And the javascript is like this:

```
/* first let's define "$a_variable_from_somewhere_that_is_a_number" so it helps you understand this question: */
var $a_variable_from_somewhere_that_is_a_number = 57;

/* ok and here is the javascript */
var another_number = $a_variable_from_somewhere_that_is_a_number
```

Now, I want to combine these two numbers into a single javascript variable.

So I write this javascript:

```
var php_number = parseInt(<?= $the_number ?>);
var javascript_number = parseInt(another_number);
var combined_number = php_number + javascript_number;
```

And to see if it worked:

```
Did it work? <script type="text/javascript">document.write(combined_number);</script>
```

I tried it, but the value is returned as "NaN", meaning it didn't work.

So how can I get it to work?

---

**UPDATE:**

I got it working!! I'm not sure what I did wrong at first because I kept trying stuff until it worked.

Here is the working code *(this is the full contents of test-page.php)*:

```
<?php
$the_number = file_get_contents("count.txt");
?>

PHP Number: <?= $the_number ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $a_variable_from_somewhere_that_is_a_number = 25;
    var another_number = $a_variable_from_somewhere_that_is_a_number

    var php_number = parseInt(<?= $the_number ?>);
    var javascript_number = parseInt(another_number);
    var combined_number = php_number + javascript_number;
</script>

<br /><br />
Did it work? <script type="text/javascript">document.write(combined_number);</script>
```

Comment: Check here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @elclanrs thanks, I'm reading it..

Comment: What are `php_number` and `javascript_number` respectively? What is `$the_number`?

Comment: What's the generated source?

Comment: @MattBall `$the_number` is defined from file.txt in the php code in my question above. `php_number` is a variable I tried to make using `$the_number`, except parsed so that I can perform a mathematical operation properly.

Comment: @SLaks you're right, I should check the source, one moment.

Comment: I understand that. **What are their values?**

Comment: @SLaks The source does not return any errors.

Comment: @MattBall the value of `php_number` for this question is the parseInt of 25 (it is the number in file.txt), and the value of `javascript_number` is the parseInt of 57.

Comment: @elclanrs I tried it and implemented it, but all that did was allow me to display the number, but did not allow me to convert the number into a javascript variable nor allow me to use that value in a javascript function.

Comment: I updated the question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone wants to leave a comment but not give an actual answer, I'll just post the answer to my own question since I solved it:

Here is the working code *(this is the full contents of test-page.php)*:

```
<?php
$the_number = file_get_contents("count.txt");
?>

PHP Number: <?= $the_number ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $a_variable_from_somewhere_that_is_a_number = 25;
    var another_number = $a_variable_from_somewhere_that_is_a_number

    var php_number = parseInt(<?= $the_number ?>);
    var javascript_number = parseInt(another_number);
    var combined_number = php_number + javascript_number;
</script>

<br /><br />
Did it work? <script type="text/javascript">document.write(combined_number);</script>
```

So apparently it is possible to include php code ***within*** javascript.